# Print all dictionaries and a variables

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have like 10 dictionaries and I want to print all the dictionaries with all the keys inside.

```
Dict1 = {}
...
Dict10 = {}
```

We could do:

```
print(list(Dict1.keys()))
...
print(list(Dict10.keys()))
```

But is there a code more simple to do this? Like a `for` loop?
I'm working on a project where:

1. Operator types get_report
2. The program looks for all dictionaries in another .py file and print all the keys from every dictionary

Comment: put your dicts into a list. then iterate over the list. you gain nothing by having N variables named dict1... dictN

Comment: You shouldn't have 10 variables. Use a dict of dicts or list of dicts. Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/4046632

Comment: And by the way, - _The program looks for all dictionaries in another .py file and print all the keys from every dictionary_ - depending on the use case you may be better using JSON if the only purpose of the second py fie is to define bunch of dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python `globals()` store all variable as a dictionary

```
dict1 = {1: 1, 2: 2}
dict2 = {6: 1, 7: 2}
dict3 = {4: 1, 3: 2}
var = globals()

for i in range(1, 11):
    dict_name = f"dict{i}"
    if var.get(dict_name):
        keys = var[dict_name].keys()
        print(list(keys))
```

@timegb suggested this might get crashed. So better approach to use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to handle unknown keys

Comment: technically correct, but bad coding style. for example, this code crashes if there aren't exactly ten dicts.

Comment: The main problem is that it rely on `globals()`. This should be proper nested data structure.